# Horizontal scrollbar ever visible

Tags: angularjs, html, css, lumx

I'm develping a webapp using Angular + Lumx.
I'm implementing a dialog in which there are a table with a lot of columns and a lot of rows so it scrolls even horizontally even vertically.

The problem is that the horizontal scrollbar is visible only at the end of the page. But in this way it is not clear that the user can also scrolls horizontally.

Is there a way to make the horizontal scrollbar always visible?

Thanks a lot!

As you can see in the screens below, the horizontal scrollbar is visibile only if I'm at the end of the page

[image]

After scrolling vertically at the end of the page, I can see it

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what is happening right now

Comment: What browser are you using to test? if you are using a Mac it hides the scrollbars - http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/displaying-scroll-bar

Comment: @user3471528. Althought this question was a log time, I would be happy if you could share the solution. I have this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS the scrollbars hide! There is a system preference for this.

There is also a long thread concerning this here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6246777

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This should make the horizontal scrollbar always visible.

```
html {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

or

```
    html,body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
```